# Set a specific character to a certain font

Tags: fonts, pdftex, textcomp

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{helvet} 
\begin{document}

\textcolonmonetary % this character can be printed if i remove the helvet pacakge

\end{document}
```

If I use \usepackage{helvet} the line \textcolonmonetary fails with:

```
Package textcomp Error: Symbol \textcolonmonetary not provided by
(textcomp)                font family phv in TS1 encoding.
(textcomp)                Default family used instead.
```

That command comes from the \textcolonmonetary package. The character is the Costa Rican colón (₡).

Is there anyway I can just wrap that character in a specific font? If so, how do I find out which font supports that character and which commands would I use?

This is for PDF LaTeX, btw, not XeTeX and no I can't switch.

Comment: Your mwe doesn't relect the problem you are describing!

Comment: Well, in your example, you don't need to do anything. But if you've switched to sans-serif, you could switch back to serif to typeset the symbol. Probably not a great solution typographically, but will compile without error (and actually typeset the symbol).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Is my example compiling for you 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could, if you wished, do something like this. I'm assuming you are switching to sans-serif font and that the symbol is required in this context. So CM Sans is a better option than CM Roman.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{helvet}
\let\oldtextcolonmonetary\textcolonmonetary
\renewcommand*\textcolonmonetary{{\fontfamily{cmss}\selectfont\oldtextcolonmonetary}}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
abc \textcolonmonetary % this character can be printed when I remove the helvet pacakge
abc
\end{document}
```

[image: symbols switch]

There are better ways to do this, but if you just want a quick fix and something which will at least get the symbol typeset, this should work.

Comment: @avoliva Good! It is a bit rough-and-ready, but it should at least print something reasonable.

Comment: It prints the character correctly, also works for other characters like \textbaht and \textwon. Thanks again!