# Insert ₡ belonging to Costa Rica

Tags: fonts, symbols, fontspec, unicode, unicode-math

How can I insert this currency symbol in `LaTeX`? It is called **Colon** and is used in some South American countries.

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. Possible related here? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226602/set-a-specific-character-to-a-certain-font

Comment: @Sebastiano I saw that in the symbols list, but there is was listed with only one line through it.

Comment: This is one of typical questions: how to print a character xy. And OP is able to insert this character in the text editor (see the title of this thread, for example). The the answer is simple: use such character in your source text, ₡100 for example. And use Unicode TeX engine and appropriate Unicode font.

Comment: I like your answer @wipet. Unfortunately, I'm using Overleaf, and can't change compiler or my document messes up (pdflatex select, btw).

Comment: Overleaf supports XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX, see Menu / Compiler.

Comment: @daleif Yes it is true. In fact I have not put the question as a duplicate. My best regards.

Comment: @wipet I know, but the whole document has been already done with pdflatex, and it would be a headache to adapt all to the new compiler (I've tried, and appearance changes too much)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a construction with the help of `\ooalign` that superimposes glyphs.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\Colon}{{%
  \ooalign{%
    \hidewidth\raisebox{0.2ex}{/}\kern0.1em\hidewidth\cr
    C\cr
    \hidewidth\kern0.1em\raisebox{0.2ex}{/}\hidewidth\cr
  }%
}}

\begin{document}

You owe me \Colon 100

\end{document}
```

First a `/`, almost centered, but pushed a bit to the left; then a full width `C`, then another `/`, centered, but pushed a bit to the right. The two slashes are slightly raised.

Why not simply raising two slashes slightly separated from each other? There are two reasons:

1. the slash has quite wide sidebearings;
2. with `\ooalign`, the height and depth are determined by the first item and the last respectively.

Reason 2 would require a phantom with a raised slash, so there's no efficiency gain in raising two boxes.

[image]

Comment: With XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and `fontspec`, the main font may have the character ₡ (U+20A1 COLON SIGN).

Comment: this seems like a good solution. How could I force to insert one blank space between currency and 100?

Comment: @thmasker You may not need the space in every situation. Just do `\Colon~100` when you need the space.